Why does uploading work, but downloading throws authentication error?
I'm using Nodejs with the javascript sdk, and accountName with accountkey.
I'm following the documentation here: [https://learn.miacrosoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-javascript)
As a test,
i'm doing this to upload:
async function UploadFile(fileSystemClient: DataLakeFileSystemClient{
    const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("my-directory/test.jpeg")
    fileClient.uploadFile("test.jpeg")
}

this works, and I'm able to see the image in the container.
however, when I do:

async function DownloadFile(fileSystemClient: DataLakeFileSystemClient) {
   const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("my-directory/test.jpeg")
   await fileClient.readToFile("test-downloaded.jpeg")
}

It throws a 401 error:
code: NoAuthenticationInformation
name: RestError
message: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
www-authenticate: 'Bearer authorization\_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/04877f06-fddd-4eec-ab16-bff4affcd5e1/oauth2/authorize resource\_id=https://storage.azure.com'

Any idea what is happening?


Why does uploading work, but downloading throws authentication error?

The error maybe you are trying to authenticate with both Azure AD and Account key authentication.
I used below code with account key authentication it downloads the image successfully.
Code:
async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    readableStream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
    readableStream.on('error', reject);
  });
}

async function main() {
  const accountName = "venkat7891";
  const fileSystemName = "test";
  const directoryName = "sample";
  const fileName = "image stamp.jpg";
  const accountKey = "zzzz";

  const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
  const dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(
    `https://${accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net`,
    sharedKeyCredential
  );

  const fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient(fileSystemName);
  const directoryClient = fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient(directoryName);
  const fileClient = directoryClient.getFileClient(fileName);

  const response = await fileClient.read();
  const buffer = await streamToBuffer(response.readableStreamBody);
  fs.writeFileSync(fileName, buffer);
  console.log(`Downloaded file ${fileName} with size ${buffer.length} bytes`);
}

main().catch(err => {
  console.error("Error downloading file:", err.message);
});

Output:
Downloaded file image stamp.jpg with size 12754 bytes

File:

Reference:
Azure Storage File Data Lake client library for JavaScript | Microsoft Learn
